# how to use TLSv1.2 in java

Tags: java, tls1.2

I have a java chat app using TLS, but when I use Wireshark to capture data the protocol column display value "TCP", why does it not show as "TLS". What's happen with my code?

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(
    this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+"lib/ca.crt")
);

InputStream is=this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+"lib/plainclient.jks");
KeyStore clientKeys = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
clientKeys.load(is,"xuanthinh".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory clientKeyManager = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
clientKeyManager.init(clientKeys,"xuanthinh".toCharArray());

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
is=this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+"lib/serverpub.jks");
ks.load(is,"xuanthinh".toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory trustManager = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
trustManager.init(ks);
//use keys to create SSLSoket
ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ssl.init(
    clientKeyManager.getKeyManagers(), trustManager.getTrustManagers(), 
    SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
);
```

Comment: Which port are you using?

Answer (score 2):

They are different protocols, and both are used when transferring encrypted content.

Have a read on the [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_(OSI_model)) for network protocols as this explains where each protocol sits relative to each other.

TCP is part of the Layer 4 (Transport Layer), whilst TLS is part of Layer 6 (Presentation Layer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what client you're using from the snippet. But doing this with Jersey/CXF i usually just set the http.protocols value. This link has some helpful information: https://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7